# VBA - How to select HTML href link containing a word

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I am attempting to select only the href link that contains "Deviation." The current VBA i am using is as follows.

```
Sub Code_Spectrum()

Dim URL As String, UN As String, PW As String
Dim IE As Object
Dim HTMLDoc As Object
Dim objC As Object
Dim elems As Object
Dim l As Long, sel As Object, x As Long, str As String
Dim e As Object
Dim t As Integer

With IE.document

For Each e In IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
        If e.classname = "edit-schedules" Then
            If t < 1 Then
                t = t + 1
                GoTo Line3
            Else
                e.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
Line3:
    Next e
End With
```

This code selects the second href link, however the link is not always the second one. There are some instances that there are 4 href codes and the position varies, as well as the schedule shift ID varies. Is there a way to click just the href containing "deviation" in the link?

```html
<table width="100%" class="schedule-detail-grid" id="grid1" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
   <tr>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td class="detail-cell scheduled-interval-cell whiteText sp-left-edge" id="A1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="detail-cell scheduled-interval-cell whiteText" id="B1">
         UHCMAE - Only
      </td>
      <td class="detail-cell scheduled-interval-cell whiteText" id="C1">
         Mon 7:00 AM - Mon 3:30 PM
      </td>
      <td class="detail-cell scheduled-interval-cell whiteText" id="D1">&nbsp; 
      </td>
      <td class="detail-cell scheduled-interval-cell whiteText" id="E1">    
         <a class="edit-schedules" href="/spectrum/operations/scheduledBreakCreateDisplay.do?method=createBreakDisplay&amp;scheduledShiftId=221749432">Break</a>
      </td>
      <td class="detail-cell scheduled-interval-cell whiteText" id="F1">&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="detail-cell scheduled-interval-cell whiteText" id="G1">
         <a class="edit-schedules" href="/spectrum/operations/deviationCreateDisplay.do?method=createNewDeviation&amp;scheduledShiftId=221749432">Deviation</a>
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's the only link containing that word, just loop through all the `a` tagnames - which you are already doing - and grab the `innerText` property.

```
Dim aTag As Object

For Each aTag In ie.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
    If aTag.innertext = "Deviation" Then
        aTag.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next aTag
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
ie.document.querySelector("[href*=deviation]").Click
```

The above answer depends on whether deviation only also appears in the `href` attribute for the element(s) with inner text `deviation`

This is based on a CSS attribute = value combination where it looks for first element with `href` attribute having value containing (`*`) `deviation` .

You could make more specific by adding in lengthening the string to match on in the `href` to `/spectrum/operations/deviation`:

```
ie.document.querySelector("[href*='/spectrum/operations/deviation']").Click
```

and adding a class selector e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector(".edit-schedules[href*='/spectrum/operations/deviation']").Click
```